# Alterar cor de commandButton?

Tags: java, jsf

Gostaria de alterar a cor de um commandButton, na verdade de vários, queria deixar setado "editar", "excluir"... etc

Meu código está assim.

```
<p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-trash" actionListener="#{MBFabricante.prepararExcluir}"
    oncomplete="PF('dlgFabExcluir').show();"
    update=":frmFabExcluir:pnlFabExcluir" />
```

Queria alterar a cor do icon

Comment: Já que você está usando um componente do primefaces, uma possibilidade seria de detectar as classes do CSS responsável pela customização do `button` no framework.

Comment: Isso que não consegui, pois sem acesso a ele

Answer (score 2):

Use a classe `.ui-button` do `primefaces`, veja no exemplo:

```
.ui-button{
    background: red !important;
}
```

O resultado: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Neste exemplo uso um arquivo .css externo. Você pode conferir que esta classe consta na [Documentação](https://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_6_1.pdf) do Primefaces.

Comment: Aqueles casos que o `!important` ajuda.